# Can I use Hibernate Envers if I just want to keep deleted Entities around?

Tags: hibernate-envers

Right now we don't delete entities, but set a flag to "inactive" in the table (and filter these entities out for normal operations). Someone pointed me to Hibernate Envers, but it looks a little bit like overkill to me. My questions are:

- Can we use Envers to perform our mechanism (active/inactive flag)?
- If not, can Envers store a copy of a deleted entity in an archive table, but don't do any versioning / auditing stuff?
- Are there lightweight alternatives for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Envers here, by extending the audit listener and ignoring insert/update events, however I agree that's an overkill.

Simply using an active flag with a dedicated DAO method or writing a simple Hibernate event listener should be much better suited for this task.